# Javascript : how to push into object's attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I've got something like this:

```
var test={
    arr : [1,2],
    number : 5
}

(test.arr).push(3);
```

It says: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined "`.
So how can i push a number or string into 'test.arr'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do:

```
test.arr.push(3);
```

so:

```
var test={
    arr : [1,2],
    number : 5
}
test.arr.push(3);
console.log( test.arr ); //gives [1,2,3]
```